# Unwrap object to circular UV island

Tags: uv, add-on

Trying to unwrap my characters chest, and trying to make the UV islands into circles, I had done it once before, but i can't remeber how i actually did it. Here's a screen shot  of what i did:[image]

here's what i got: [image]

TL:DR take a lumpy ciruclar UV map, make it circular. I know it can be done, just not the right addon/hotkeys

Comment: One idea that comes to mind is to create shape keys and on one key cast the topology to a sphere, then unwrap on that shape key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the solution on my own!

Here's what happened that wasn't apparent from the errors from the addon: in the moset center area, the geometry look as such:[image]

The fact that the geometry itself wasn't a selectable edge loop was causing the Magic UV addon to fail in unexpected ways. Also, the error codes it was giving were not helpful in the least to trying to triage the problem. The solution was to make sure the UV island was nothing but complete edge loops.

Comment: hello, so maybe tell a little bit about what tool in Magic UV you've used?